# Access violation when calling Delphi DLL from C# in a multi-threaded environment

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, delphi, pinvoke

I am calling a DLL function written in Delphi XE2 from C# using P/Invoke. It appears to be working when calls are made sequentially from a single thread. However, when multiple threads are calling the function, the C# host application throws `System.AccessViolationException` seemingly at random.

Why does the code below trigger an access violation and how do I fix this?

Minimum Delphi library code for reproducing the problem:

```
library pinvokeproblem;

{$R *.res}

uses Windows, SysUtils;

procedure Test(const testByte: byte); stdcall;
begin
  OutputDebugString(PWideChar(IntToStr(testByte)));
end;

exports Test;

end.
```

Minimum C# host application code to reproduce the problem:

```
[DllImport(
    "pinvokeproblem.dll",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
    EntryPoint = "Test")]
private static extern void Test(byte testByte);

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) // more iterations = better chance to fail
    {
        int threadCount = 10;
        Parallel.For(1, threadCount, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threadCount }, test =>
        {
            byte byteArgument = 42;
            Test(byteArgument);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Iteration {0}: {1}", test, byteArgument));
        });
     }
}
```

Additional information:

- Platform is x64 Windows 7. C# host application built for x86 in .NET 4.0, Delphi DLL compiled for 32-bit.
- The library appears to be working OK when used in a multi-threaded Delphi host application.
- An MSVC version of the DLL with the function signature `extern __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall Test(char testByte)` works fine with the C# host (which suggests this is somehow specific to Delphi).
- The code will not fail if the library function has no return value (`void`) and arguments.
- Changing the calling convention in both code to `cdecl` did not help.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like maybe the issue is the OutputDebugString(PWideChar(IntToStr(testByte))); in your delphi code.  I am not sure you can convert a single byte to a WideChar.  I am not a Delphi expert, but something just feels wrong about that statement.

Comment: @mageos That statement is perfectly fine

Comment: @mageos: Thank you. That code is valid and the issue does not seem to occur in my Delphi code at all. When I wrapped the Delphi code into a `try..catch` block, I never managed to catch an exception.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All you have to do is set [`IsMultiThread`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.IsMultiThread) to `True` (as the first line in your DLL's main `begin`..`end` block) to switch the memory manager to a thread-safe mode:

```
IsMultiThread := True;
```

Comment: OMG, how did I forget that! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. It's rather easy to forget. I just had a very similar problem not too long ago, also with C# interop by coincidence.

Comment: @TOndrej: Thank you, it never occurred to me to set this manually (in my defense, normally I use COM interop where class factories set this automatically or otherwise I launch my own threads which also do the same).

Comment: Exactly, normally you don't need to do this because the relevant units and classes do it for you as part of their initialization.

Comment: My code base has `IsMultiThread := True` in an initialization section of a unit that is always used. Frankly IsMultiThread is something of an anachronism today.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I agree. Contemporary language runtimes can deal with multi-threaded memory management very well, so I guess there's little to be gained by a dual STA/MTA memory manager model and especially one that occassionally needs to be nudged into one mode or another. At very least, `IsMultiThread` should be enabled by default.